# Flow using array values as type

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have an array with the values:

```
const currencies = ['USD', 'BRL', 'EUR']
// The true array has more then 15 currencies values
```

I want to avoid doing this to avoid code duplication:

```
type Currencies = 'USD' | 'BRL' | 'EUR'
```

Is it possible to use those values as types? I tried to do that:

```
type Currencies = $Values<currencies>
```

But I got an error because $Values are only for objects.

What is the best way of not duplicating the code since I already have those values in an array.

Comment: the `Currencies` in the 2nd code line will be always 'USD' per javascript grammar.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, 'coz I don't know anything about flow.

Comment: This flow issue might give you more information: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/961 As far as I can tell from the ticket, this isn't supported yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell there isn't a way to do this currently with flow using an array.

One approach is to turn your array into an object and use `$Keys` with `typeof`

```
const currencies = ['USD', 'BRL', 'EUR'];
const currenciesObj = currencies.reduce((agg, next) => ({...agg, [next]: true}), {});

type Currencies = $Keys<typeof currenciesObj>;
```

Comment: But the type of `currenciesObj` will be `{}` not `{USD: true, BRL: true, EUR: true}` so this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Jamie's version will create another object `currenciesObj` which is just created for the purpose of types and will stay in the code even types removed while minifying the code.

Below is the code that doesn't need creating a new object.

```
const xs: Array<'hi' | 'bye'> = ['hi', 'bye'];

type ArrayValues<TArr> = $Call<<T>(Array<T>) => T, TArr>;

("hi": ArrayValues<typeof xs>); // OK
("foo": ArrayValues<typeof xs>); // ERROR, "foo" not in 'hi' | 'bye'
(1: ArrayValues<typeof xs>); // ERROR, number is incompatible with string
```